# ffmpeg /dev/video1: No space left on device

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, usb, usb-drive

While converting and redirecting USB camera stream to a multicast ip I'm facing below error.

**ffmpeg -f v4l2 -i /dev/video1 -s 720x480 -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:v mpeg2video -aspect 4:3 -r 30 -g 15 -ar 0 -streamid 0:48 -bf 2 -b:v 100k -bufsize 400k -maxrate 3825k -f rtp_mpegts rtp://239.0.2.2:5001**

ffmpeg version 3.2.4-static http://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/  Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.4.1 (Debian 5.4.1-5) 20170205
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-debug --disable-ffplay --disable-indev=sndio --disable-outdev=sndio --cc=gcc-5 --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-gray --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg
  libavutil      55. 34.101 / 55. 34.101
  libavcodec     57. 64.101 / 57. 64.101
  libavformat    57. 56.101 / 57. 56.101
  libavdevice    57.  1.100 / 57.  1.100
  libavfilter     6. 65.100 /  6. 65.100
  libswscale      4.  2.100 /  4.  2.100
  libswresample   2.  3.100 /  2.  3.100
  libpostproc    54.  1.100 / 54.  1.100

**[video4linux2,v4l2 @ 0xb982f80] ioctl(VIDIOC_STREAMON): No space left on device
/dev/video1: No space left on device**

Below are top and free -m command outputs

## top

top - 20:10:13 up 16 min,  4 users,  load average: 0.49, 0.37, 0.28
Tasks: 257 total,   1 running, 256 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  3.4 us,  0.2 sy,  0.0 ni, 95.9 id,  0.5 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem : 13457292 total, 12299768 free,   650672 used,   506852 buff/cache
KiB Swap:  3670012 total,  3670012 free,        0 used. 12710776 avail Mem

PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
 4095 root      20   0  333376 153296 138660 S  25.9  1.1   1:09.41 ffmpeg
 1551 root      20   0   84804  40076  17756 S   0.7  0.3   0:24.00 Xorg.bin
 2574 user      20   0   66900  27436  21268 S   0.7  0.2   0:11.30 gnome-terminal-
 4373 root      20   0    7800   3852   3196 R   0.7  0.0   0:00.03 top
  610 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.3  0.0   0:00.03 kworker/4:2
 3762 user      20   0  816928 217120  75100 S   0.3  1.6   0:56.34 firefox
 4240 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.3  0.0   0:02.24 kworker/0:2
    1 root      20   0   27464   7508   5044 S   0.0  0.1   0:01.95 systemd
    2 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kthreadd
    3 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 ksoftirqd/0
    5 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kworker/0:0H
    7 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:01.29 rcu_sched

## free -m

```
          total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
```

Mem:          13141         621       12025           2         495       12426
Swap:          3583           0        3583

## cat /proc/meminfo |grep -i vmalloc

VmallocTotal:     524288 kB
VmallocUsed:      204736 kB
VmallocChunk:     316560 kB

P.S:: There is already an instance of ffmpeg running on the machine on /dev/video0.

Any help in resolving issue would be greatly appreciated

Comment: See [Markdown help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) to see how to properly format your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved with

[Write two webcam video with avconv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11741371/write-two-webcam-video-with-avconv)

And had increase vmalloc memory from 128M to 512M